# Limit still undefined after rationalizing.

Tags: calculus

I am trying to evaluate:

$$\lim_{x \to 4}\frac{\sqrt{5-x} - 1}{2-\sqrt{x}}.$$

Even though I tried rationalizing both denominator and numerator, I still end up with the functioning being undefined.

How can I solve this without rationalizing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone was wondering, after rationalizing I had gotten

$$\lim_{x \to 4}\frac{4 - x}{(2-\sqrt{x})(\sqrt{5-x}+x)}.$$

Of which you need to factor $(4-x)$ to $(2-\sqrt{x})(2+\sqrt{x})$.

From there you can guess where to go.

Answer (score 1):

Rationalizing gives :
$$\frac{\sqrt{5-x}-1}{2-\sqrt x} = \frac{(4-x)(2+\sqrt x)}{(4-x)(\sqrt{5-x}+1)}$$
I think you can find the limit from here :-)

Comment: Wait, did you use the numerator or the denominator?

Comment: Jk I got it thanks haha